# R: how to store the output of a foreach loop?

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I am trying to store the output of a foreach loop in R. The code I use is as follows:

```
tweets_all = list()
foreach(i = 1:5, .packages = c("magrittr", "foreach", "academictwitteR")) %dopar% {
  tweets_all[[i]] = bind_tweets(data_path = paste0("./data_new/data", i), output_format = "tidy")
  }
```

So basically I am following the logic of storing the output of a for loop, by firstly creating an empty list `tweets_all`, and putting the output of each iteration into that list. However, the outputs were not stored in that list of `tweets_all`, the `tweets_all` list is still empty. While the output of the above code was automatically printed out like this:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 17,854 x 31
   tweet_id      user_username text  possibly_sensit~ conversation_id author_id source lang  created_at user_url user_protected user_created_at user_profile_im~
   <chr>         <chr>         <chr> <lgl>            <chr>           <chr>     <chr>  <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <lgl>          <chr>           <chr>           
 1 146544706849~ kwcpainter    RT @~ FALSE            14654470684960~ 349969646 Tweet~ en    2021-11-2~ ""       FALSE          2011-08-07T00:~ https://pbs.twi~
 2 146544705236~ Deepdiver600  RT @~ FALSE            14654470523604~ 14195830~ Twitt~ en    2021-11-2~ ""       FALSE          2021-07-26T08:~ https://pbs.twi~
 3 146544705200~ Jabroni_Niner RT @~ FALSE            14654470520079~ 468137468 Twitt~ en    2021-11-2~ ""       FALSE          2012-01-19T06:~ https://pbs.twi~
 4 146544704385~ St_Diogenes   RT @~ FALSE            14654470438585~ 13997184~ Twitt~ en    2021-11-2~ ""       FALSE          2021-06-01T13:~ https://pbs.twi~
 5 146544703368~ kristinkgl    RT @~ FALSE            14654470336874~ 10936760~ Twitt~ en    2021-11-2~ ""       FALSE          2013-01-16T00:~ https://pbs.twi~
 6 146544702777~ ivory319      RT @~ FALSE            14654470277733~ 48449979~ Twitt~ en    2021-11-2~ ""       FALSE          2016-01-25T10:~ https://pbs.twi~
 7 146544702475~ VeritasTB2    RT @~ FALSE            14654470247535~ 85285252~ Twitt~ en    2021-11-2~ ""       FALSE          2017-04-14T11:~ https://pbs.twi~
 8 146544702070~ scot79033947  RT @~ FALSE            14654470207061~ 13556114~ Twitt~ en    2021-11-2~ ""       FALSE          2021-01-30T20:~ https://pbs.twi~
 9 146544701752~ ukcitizen007  RT @~ FALSE            14654470175267~ 12242558~ Twitt~ en    2021-11-2~ ""       FALSE          2020-02-03T08:~ https://pbs.twi~
10 146544701752~ lucashartley~ RT @~ FALSE            14654470175224~ 14450708~ Twitt~ en    2021-11-2~ ""       FALSE          2021-10-04T16:~ https://pbs.twi~
# ... with 17,844 more rows, and 18 more variables: user_description <chr>, user_verified <lgl>, user_name <chr>, user_location <chr>,
#   user_pinned_tweet_id <chr>, retweet_count <int>, like_count <int>, quote_count <int>, user_tweet_count <int>, user_list_count <int>,
#   user_followers_count <int>, user_following_count <int>, sourcetweet_type <chr>, sourcetweet_id <chr>, sourcetweet_text <chr>, sourcetweet_lang <chr>,
#   sourcetweet_author_id <chr>, in_reply_to_user_id <chr>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 6,741 x 31
   tweet_id  user_username text  created_at conversation_id source author_id lang  possibly_sensit~ user_profile_im~ user_created_at user_verified user_location
   <chr>     <chr>         <chr> <chr>      <chr>           <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <lgl>            <chr>            <chr>           <lgl>         <chr>        
 1 14312213~ gpalmen       RT @~ 2021-08-2~ 14312213388286~ Twitt~ 22672330  en    FALSE            https://pbs.twi~ 2009-03-03T20:~ FALSE         "Mook"       
 2 14312213~ loyddaroyd    RT @~ 2021-08-2~ 14312213222108~ TwitP~ 255531287 en    FALSE            https://pbs.twi~ 2011-02-21T15:~ FALSE         "FL, USA"    
 3 14312213~ realdhbenson  RT @~ 2021-08-2~ 14312213148538~ Twitt~ 89227576~ en    FALSE            https://pbs.twi~ 2017-08-01T06:~ FALSE         "British Col~
 4 14312213~ AliceBallard~ RT @~ 2021-08-2~ 14312213037349~ Twitt~ 70978902~ en    FALSE            https://pbs.twi~ 2016-03-15T17:~ FALSE         " USA"       
 5 14312213~ scarredbushi~ RT @~ 2021-08-2~ 14312213004758~ Twitt~ 75023725~ en    FALSE            https://pbs.twi~ 2016-07-05T07:~ FALSE         "Hinata Spri~
 6 14312212~ Jamie04042155 RT @~ 2021-08-2~ 14312212986598~ Twitt~ 11001545~ en    FALSE            https://pbs.twi~ 2019-02-25T22:~ FALSE          NA          
 7 14312212~ BertvantZand  RT @~ 2021-08-2~ 14312212906990~ Twitt~ 12808028~ en    FALSE            https://pbs.twi~ 2013-03-19T15:~ FALSE          NA          
 8 14312212~ jussaguy2u    RT @~ 2021-08-2~ 14312212745424~ Twitt~ 23021090  en    FALSE            https://pbs.twi~ 2009-03-06T03:~ FALSE         "Nunya"      
 9 14312212~ sandrabloomB  RT @~ 2021-08-2~ 14312212665272~ Twitt~ 40407170~ en    FALSE            https://pbs.twi~ 2015-10-25T18:~ FALSE         "Global"     
10 14312212~ b_indaclouds  RT @~ 2021-08-2~ 14312212643881~ Twitt~ 525362634 en    FALSE            https://pbs.twi~ 2012-03-15T13:~ FALSE         "NC"         
# ... with 6,731 more rows, and 18 more variables: user_name <chr>, user_protected <lgl>, user_url <chr>, user_description <chr>, user_pinned_tweet_id <chr>,
#   retweet_count <int>, like_count <int>, quote_count <int>, user_tweet_count <int>, user_list_count <int>, user_followers_count <int>,
#   user_following_count <int>, sourcetweet_type <chr>, sourcetweet_id <chr>, sourcetweet_text <chr>, sourcetweet_lang <chr>, sourcetweet_author_id <chr>,
#   in_reply_to_user_id <chr>

[[3]]
# A tibble: 6,439 x 31
   tweet_id     user_username text  created_at source possibly_sensit~ conversation_id lang  author_id in_reply_to_use~ user_name user_verified user_profile_im~
   <chr>        <chr>         <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <lgl>            <chr>           <chr> <chr>     <chr>            <chr>     <lgl>         <chr>           
 1 13961156432~ Adaya77       "To ~ 2021-05-2~ Twitt~ FALSE            13961156432298~ en    16395830  NA               "Adaya77" FALSE         https://pbs.twi~
 2 13961153462~ PeaknikMicki  "CDC~ 2021-05-2~ Twitt~ FALSE            13961153462059~ en    88940731~ NA               "Peaknik~ FALSE         https://pbs.twi~
 3 13961146269~ benstu37      "RT ~ 2021-05-2~ Twitt~ FALSE            13961146269376~ en    741552206 NA               "BOB the~ FALSE         https://pbs.twi~
 4 13961144860~ WorthingtonE~ "RT ~ 2021-05-2~ Twitt~ FALSE            13961144860339~ en    70883242  NA               "Proneto~ FALSE         https://pbs.twi~
 5 13961143524~ T2Rantor      "RT ~ 2021-05-2~ Twitt~ FALSE            13961143524539~ en    10372470~ NA               "Rantor"  FALSE         https://pbs.twi~
 6 13961122762~ marina_sapir  "Cyc~ 2021-05-2~ Twitt~ FALSE            13961122762776~ en    98851699~ NA               "Marina ~ FALSE         https://pbs.twi~
 7 13961121089~ Yorksceptic   "Two~ 2021-05-2~ Twitt~ FALSE            13961121089039~ en    99938813  NA               "Sir Ian" FALSE         https://pbs.twi~
 8 13961116823~ SouthILdream~ "RT ~ 2021-05-2~ Twitt~ FALSE            13961116823012~ en    83728699~ NA               "Red Red~ FALSE         https://pbs.twi~
 9 13961101930~ TonyGreyMan   "RT ~ 2021-05-2~ Twitt~ FALSE            13961101930214~ en    11766208~ NA               "Tony"    FALSE         https://pbs.twi~
10 13961099635~ fgiangerelli  "RT ~ 2021-05-2~ Twitt~ FALSE            13961099635844~ en    81932295~ NA               "MAGA Fr~ FALSE         https://pbs.twi~
# ... with 6,429 more rows, and 18 more variables: user_created_at <chr>, user_description <chr>, user_protected <lgl>, user_url <chr>, user_location <chr>,
#   user_pinned_tweet_id <chr>, retweet_count <int>, like_count <int>, quote_count <int>, user_tweet_count <int>, user_list_count <int>,
#   user_followers_count <int>, user_following_count <int>, sourcetweet_type <chr>, sourcetweet_id <chr>, sourcetweet_text <chr>, sourcetweet_lang <chr>,
#   sourcetweet_author_id <chr>

[[4]]
# A tibble: 5,067 x 31
   tweet_id            user_username   text     created_at author_id possibly_sensit~ conversation_id source lang  in_reply_to_use~ user_protected user_location
   <chr>               <chr>           <chr>    <chr>      <chr>     <lgl>            <chr>           <chr>  <chr> <chr>            <lgl>          <chr>        
 1 1404971960656961539 VronikaSDB1     "RT @Yv~ 2021-06-1~ 572861879 FALSE            14049719606569~ Twitt~ en    NA               FALSE          Monaco       
 2 1404959613712277507 FranceBis92     "RT @Yv~ 2021-06-1~ 10330186~ FALSE            14049596137122~ Twitt~ en    NA               FALSE          France       
 3 1404947871963783173 NoelSully11     "RT @Ri~ 2021-06-1~ 78233909~ FALSE            14049478719637~ Twitt~ en    NA               FALSE          United States
 4 1404946634967031811 RiekiErasmusAtt "RT @tn~ 2021-06-1~ 10070835~ FALSE            14049466349670~ Twitt~ en    NA               FALSE          Roodepoort/H~
 5 1404946589911715841 RiekiErasmusAtt "Can th~ 2021-06-1~ 10070835~ FALSE            14049465899117~ Twitt~ en    NA               FALSE          Roodepoort/H~
 6 1404946316858478597 jasperlionel    "RT @tn~ 2021-06-1~ 99329128~ FALSE            14049463168584~ Twitt~ en    NA               FALSE          NA           
 7 1404942539992481794 CasseJ2         "RT @Yv~ 2021-06-1~ 13936841~ FALSE            14049425399924~ Twitt~ en    NA               FALSE          NA           
 8 1404940933125181443 mtz_holly       "RT @Yv~ 2021-06-1~ 13660867~ FALSE            14049409331251~ Twitt~ en    NA               FALSE          NA           
 9 1404939998722412546 jean2florette   "first-~ 2021-06-1~ 84418207~ FALSE            14049399987224~ Twitt~ en    NA               FALSE          NA           
10 1404939283258089484 corijkon        "RT @Yv~ 2021-06-1~ 11078537~ FALSE            14049392832580~ Twitt~ en    NA               FALSE          NA           
# ... with 5,057 more rows, and 19 more variables: user_description <chr>, user_profile_image_url <chr>, user_url <chr>, user_verified <lgl>, user_name <chr>,
#   user_created_at <chr>, user_pinned_tweet_id <chr>, retweet_count <int>, like_count <int>, quote_count <int>, user_tweet_count <int>, user_list_count <int>,
#   user_followers_count <int>, user_following_count <int>, sourcetweet_type <chr>, sourcetweet_id <chr>, sourcetweet_text <chr>, sourcetweet_lang <chr>,
#   sourcetweet_author_id <chr>

[[5]]
# A tibble: 12,386 x 31
   tweet_id            user_username   text  created_at lang  conversation_id possibly_sensit~ author_id source user_protected user_description user_profile_im~
   <chr>               <chr>           <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>           <lgl>            <chr>     <chr>  <lgl>          <chr>            <chr>           
 1 1490748491282452480 CarolynClburr   RT @~ 2022-02-0~ en    14907484912824~ FALSE            84501053~ Twitt~ FALSE          ""               https://pbs.twi~
 2 1490748475381719040 kathrine_munk   RT @~ 2022-02-0~ en    14907484753817~ FALSE            13788268~ Twitt~ FALSE          "I love aquariu~ https://pbs.twi~
 3 1490748465894367234 zenjk0          RT @~ 2022-02-0~ en    14907484658943~ FALSE            21422783  Twitt~ FALSE          "Slavic slav. S~ https://pbs.twi~
 4 1490748449490411524 ArcticTidalSurg RT @~ 2022-02-0~ en    14907484494904~ FALSE            71129108~ Twitt~ FALSE          "Drugs or vacci~ https://pbs.twi~
 5 1490748446734696449 napoliangel10   RT @~ 2022-02-0~ en    14907484467346~ FALSE            480682459 Twitt~ FALSE          "I'm not fuckin~ https://pbs.twi~
 6 1490748438463627269 brights_lights  RT @~ 2022-02-0~ en    14907484384636~ FALSE            14741131~ Twitt~ FALSE          "« Le non-sens ~ https://pbs.twi~
 7 1490748437595361282 funkymonkey374  RT @~ 2022-02-0~ en    14907484375953~ FALSE            14099191~ Twitt~ FALSE          ""               https://pbs.twi~
 8 1490748435607269378 TonyGreyMan     RT @~ 2022-02-0~ en    14907484356072~ FALSE            11766208~ Twitt~ FALSE          "The Grey Man. ~ https://pbs.twi~
 9 1490748427914948609 7_firefly       RT @~ 2022-02-0~ en    14907484279149~ FALSE            13922322~ Twitt~ FALSE          "<U+2640><U+FE0F>Patriot #TRUM~ https://pbs.twi~
10 1490748423921934337 Gingatossa1     RT @~ 2022-02-0~ en    14907484239219~ FALSE            242780839 Twitt~ FALSE          "Vegan \U0001f4~ https://pbs.twi~
# ... with 12,376 more rows, and 19 more variables: user_verified <lgl>, user_created_at <chr>, user_url <chr>, user_name <chr>, user_location <chr>,
#   user_pinned_tweet_id <chr>, retweet_count <int>, like_count <int>, quote_count <int>, user_tweet_count <int>, user_list_count <int>,
#   user_followers_count <int>, user_following_count <int>, sourcetweet_type <chr>, sourcetweet_id <chr>, sourcetweet_text <chr>, sourcetweet_lang <chr>,
#   sourcetweet_author_id <chr>, in_reply_to_user_id <chr>
```

Is there a method to store the output of each iteration into the empty list? Please give me some advice if you know how to deal with this problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
tweets_all = foreach(i = 1:5, .packages = c("magrittr", "foreach", "academictwitteR")) %dopar% {
  bind_tweets(data_path = paste0("./data_new/data", i), output_format = "tidy")
}
```